# How to code methods in your classes

Tags: class, object, methods, comparison

I need help knowing how to code a statement like "if this has been set then do this" kind of a method. For instance, I have written an Author and a Book class. In my Book class I need a method that returns the title of book. However, if the author of the book has been set (i.e. there is a method in Book that sets the author) then return the title of the book plus the authors name.

here is some of my code for these classes

```
public class Author{
  String authorFirstName;
  String authorLastName;
  int authorBirth;
  int authorDeath;

  //creates a new author object with nothing set
  public Author(){
  }

  //String l=last name, String f=frist name
  //creates new author object by setting the last and first name
  public Author(String l, String f){
    authorLastName=l;
    authroFirstName=f;
  }
//end of Author class
 } 

public class Book{
  int bookYearPublish;
  Author bookAuthor;
  String bookNumberISBN;
  String bookTitle;

  public Book(){
  }

  //String t is the title of the book
  //creats a Book object with a title
  public Book(String t){
    bookTitle=t;
  }

  //String t is the title of the book
  //Author a is the author of the book
  //creats a Book object with a title and author
  public Book(String t, Author a){
    bookTitle=t;
    bookAuthor=a;
  }

  //Author a is the author that will be set for the Book
  //sets the author of the book
  public void setAuthor(Author a){
    bookAuthor=a;
  }

  //returns the Author of the Book
  public Author getAuthor(){
    return bookAuthor;
  }

  //returns the title of Book
  //if the author is known returns a String in the form of title. last name, first name of author
  //if the year is known returns a String in the form title (year). last name, first name of author
  public String toString(){
    String title=bookTitle;
    if(bookAuthor.equals(this.getAuthor())){//I am getting a NullPointException here so this is where my problem is
      title=title+". "+bookAuthor;
    }
    if(bookYearPublish.equals(this.getYear())){
      title=bookTitle+" ("+bookYearPublish+"). "+bookAuthor;
    }
    return title;
  }

  //ends class Book
}
```

Comment: Is this an assignment or something?  If not, I'd suggest you not do this. Having one method that can basically return different things is confusing.  You will have to code around that method.  Is it returning only the title, or the title and the author? When you call the method, you won't know, so you'll have to do some sort of evaluation and/or parsing of the result.  I'd use separate getters for separate properties.

Comment: the toString() method returns the title of book unless the author and/or year of publication has been set. There are setter methods for the title, author, and year of publication. So if the author has been set then it return "Title. Author. and if the publication has been set then it return "Title (Year). Author

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, I just don't think it's a good idea. For example, you've set the title and the author,but you just want the title, you can't get it. You'll get a string with the title and the author, and you'll have to parse that string. If you want all those properties returned in one method, have that method return an array of Strings.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a getTitle() method (like the getAuthor one) with something like this

```
 public string getTitle()
{
  String s = this.title;
if(author != "" || author != null)
{
s+=this.author;
}
return s;
}
```

Comment: I do have a getTitle() method in my whole code so I will try you format and see it works. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
if(bookAuthor.equals(this.getAuthor())){
```

put

```
if(bookAuthor != null && bookAuthor.equals(this.getAuthor())){
```

But, I think this is not what you want... `this.getAuthor()` returns `bookAuthor` so it should always match...  I think what you really want is:

```
if( bookAuthor != null) {
    title=title+". "+bookAuthor;
}
```

Comment: Alright I will also try this form as well. Hopefully it works and thank you for your input

Comment: there is also a preset Author AUTHOR_NOT_SET=new Author("AUTHOR NOT SET, "");

Comment: so do I use that author instead of a null or just add it to the condition with an ||

Comment: Rather than a "special not set" author, you might consider just adding if `author==null`, output the special text.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to put the action you want to do after setting the author in your `setAuthor(Author a)` like this:

```
public void setAuthor(Author a){
bookAuthor=a;

// put the action here.
}
```